# a compiling issue using the Android virtual device

Tags: java, android

I have a question about the Android virtual device(avd)... as what you already know, that you can test your android application through avd in eclipse, and i'm getting a boring repeted thing with that.

each time I want to test my application and when I make a small change to my application, I have to run the avd again and wait for a long time till the application run(switch the device on and wait for the system to boot and then wait for the application to start,this takes approx. 15 sec)... as I said, each time I make whatever change to the program I have to go through these boaring time consuming loop :( ...

So, is there is a way to avoid these issue, and makes the avd run only for the first time and any changes can take effect quickly and only needed to restart the application without needed to stop and run the project again ??

I hope there is a way for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you're done with a debug cycle, do you close the AVD? If you keep the AVD running, it should do exactly what you're describing.

If that doesn't work for you, a look at your application manifest may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't quit the emulator. Leave it running, hit Run (or Debug) in Eclipse, and if anything changed, the program will be uploaded to the emulator again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't close the emulator. Keep it running and click debug again, it will run fast since it won't reboot. (The emulator will just re-install the app instead).